# PowerShell - question about pipeline variable

Tags: powershell

I am confused about the pipeline variable in the nested pipelines scenario.

Below is one example to replace substrings in a bunch of text files. It works as it should (I used the code snippet from another SO thread) but not too sure why it does.

```
$SourceString = 'DAT'
$ReplacementString = 'CAT'

Get-ChildItem 'C:\*.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_) -replace $SourceString,$ReplacementString | Set-Content $_.fullname
}
```

My understanding was that $_ represents the current object in the pipeline. In the above example, I can see 2 pipelines - one feeding on the Get-ChildItem (outer pipeline) and the other that saves content (inner pipeline). My doubt is regarding this Set-Content pipeline  - why is $_ in inner pipeline still  referring to the Get-ChildItem object from the outer pipeline (as it's clearly using $_.fullname to refer to GCI object) when it should be referring to the replaced string from the -replace operation?

Thanks - Steve

Comment: In the `ForEach-Object { ... }` codeblock `$_` will represent the current object whereever `$_` is used.  It does not change down the pipeline.  If another `ForEach-Object { .. }` is added to the pipeline then inside that { } codeblock the `$_` will now represent each item of that new codeblock.  Back on the outside of that block `$_` will again represent the objects of the outer `ForEach-Object` codeblock.  DId that make sense?  :)

Comment: I thought starting a new pipeline (even nested one) starts a new pipeline variable to refer to the the new pipeline objects emitted.

Comment: The description of the automatic variable [`$PSItem`(`$_`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#_) appears a little confusing here as it doesn't mean that the current item (`$_`) is assigned each time you use the `|` character. Instead, it means that it is assiged "***in commands** that perform an action on every object*" (such as [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1))

Comment: So, in summary, $_ only comes into context in a pipeline when there is a collection of objects to be iterated over? In that case doesn't the code (Get-Content $_) -replace $SourceString,$ReplacementString above emits a collection which happens to contain a single object that gets passed down the Set-Content pipeline?

Comment: @Steve No, it only takes on a new value when you _enter a new block_. Had you done ```...| Set-Content -Path { "${_}.txt"} -Value "somestring"``` - then  `$_` _inside the new block_ would have taken on the successive values of the replaced strings from the second pipeline instead (and written to a file named thereafter)

Comment: @Mathias - That's clear now. Thanks.